# Set the AssemblyVersion of a dotnet publish in an Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline via variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

You can set the AssemblyVersion in a dotnet build via command line parameters, like in this example (2024.01.25.5):

```
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:AssemblyVersion=2024.01.25.5 -p:BuildIpa=True -o ./artifacts
```

Now I want, that the AssemblyVersion is set dynamically by a YAML varibable.
Therefor I first create the variable and set the values to the wanted values.
After that, I use the variable in the bash script, that is doing the publish:

```
variables:
  DotNetVersion: '8.x'
  AssemblyVersion: $(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd)$(Rev:.r)

 - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Build iOS App
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'        
        script: |
          cd src
          dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:AssemblyVersion=$ASSEMBLYVERSION -p:BuildIpa=True -o ./artifacts
```

But this is not working. The bash script is always using the value as string:

> error CS7034: The specified version string
> '$(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd)$(Rev:.r)' does not conform to the
> required format

Why is my variable not interpreted correctly?
I already tried with `${{variables.AssemblyVersion}}` and `$[[variables.AssemblyVersion]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format `$(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd)$(Rev:.r)` is used to generate the build name ([Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) and it is not supported for variables. You may use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` as a base. Then update it by the logging command ([Override the automatically generated build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number)) if needed. Example:

```
name: $(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd)$(Rev:.r)

variables:
  AssemblyVersion: $(Build.BuildNumber)

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "$(AssemblyVersion)"

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "new build number $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(AssemblyVersion)"
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(AssemblyVersion)"
```